# Handle and trigger events from QML to C++ and viceversa

Tags: c++, qt, events, qml

I'm working with Qt, using the latest version of Qt Creator on windows 8.1. Once I finished my GUI, I tried to communicate some of my QML elements in C ++ and vice versa, i.e. send data from the two sides.

---

### Example I've tried

I had no idea how to do this, then I have forwarded to read the official documentation and examples from this site, but no one works for me.

**Code:**

```
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void cppSlot(const QString &msg) {
        qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with message:" << msg;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view(QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));
    QObject *item = view.rootObject();

    MyClass myClass;
    QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),
                     &myClass, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));

    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

But i'm getting an error:

```
C:\Users\Tomi\qml\main.cpp:20: error: cannot convert 'QQuickItem*' to 'QObject*' in initialization
     QObject *item = view.rootObject();
```

### What I want

All I need is that when a button is pressed from QML, certain data to C++ are requested and when they are ready to be sent to QML. Is this possible?, could you show me a simplistic and functional example?

Thanks!

Comment: The first pitfall most people stumble across when using Qt for the first time is, that they have their Q_OBJECT thing in the same module as their main(). This way, the "moc" compiler (meta object compiler) is not creating all that qt specific signal slot metacode and your stuff won't work. Move your MyClass to a header file and the implementation to a respective .cpp file and you will be "back in business".

Comment: But now I can't view mt elements, only a window with a white background

Comment: @TomásJuárez it does work, OP is just missing #include "main.moc" at the end of the .cpp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because the compiler isn't aware of what a `QQuickItem` is. You need to include it:

```
#include <QQuickItem>
```

`QQuickItem` is only forward-declared in `QQuickView`'s header, for example, so you can't rely on it to include `QQuickItem` for you, and shouldn't anyway.

Also, the comment about moc not working with classes defined in main.cpp is wrong; you just need to include `main.moc` after your class definition for the QObject stuff to work:

```
#include "main.moc"
```

I dislike this myth, because it turns short snippets and examples into three files, when they could be contained in just one, which is much more useful on Stack Overflow, bug trackers, etc. :)

Comment: It does not show my QML elements; if I use QApplication app(argc, argv);

    `QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();` in the main function it works, but using my example it thorws `file:///C:/Users/Tomi/build-qml-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/main.qml: File not found`, why?

Comment: Maybe they should point it out... On typical "first time user" pages, such as http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlfirststeps.html it is not mentioned at all.

Comment: @user2225104 do you mean the #include "main.moc" thing? The page you linked to doesn't really have much to do with that, but if you can find another page that you think new users might see, let me know and I'll write a patch that adds a paragraph explaining it.

Comment: @TomásJuárez, I don't know, you'd have to post more code. Perhaps just ask a new question about the next error - your original example doesn't use QQmlApplicationEngine, and the edits required would make an otherwise neat question quite messy.